# Searching the LinkedIn API without authorizing a user

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, oauth, linkedin-api

Im currently creating a PHP application that searched various Social Media and analyses the results. Now im stuck at calling the LinkedIn API.

I need to call these API's without user authentication (I need a sort of app authentication). Facebook offers a way to retrieve an access token, based on app key and secret. With Twitter I simply used my own accestoken en access secret.

I searched all day for a way to call the LinkedIn API in a similar way, but havent succeeded in finding one. I also couldn't find my own access token en secret on the LinkedIn developer's site.

Do you know how I can access the LinkedIn API from my PHP application, without the user having to login himself?

Hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LinkedIn API doesn't support non-user-authenticated requests - that is, there are no calls for which you can just use the consumer key and secret - they all require a user token and secret as well.

The LinkedIn API is designed to be used from the member's perspective, acting on behalf of a specific member - it's not designed to support general application search use cases.

Terms of use: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use

Comment: yeah that's why its lame

Comment: @Kirsten Jones
After posting a comment and mentioning you on another thread, I've just stumbled upon this answer by you - this seems like the answer to my question - no option to act as an anonymous user to get public stuff of another user?

Answer (score 0):

Like Twitter, you could use your own access token, but per the [LinkedIn guidelines](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use), you can't show anyone the information that you pull unless you use a token obtained on their behalf.

Comment: Isnt there any way to create a token based on API key and secret, so the user doesnt have to login? I know facebook offers a way to do this via https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={APPID}&client_secret={APPSECRET}

Comment: LinkedIn largely uses OAuth 1.0a like Twitter - so while a few calls can be made without having the user authenticate (just using the app's authentication), anything that requires a permission scope (as Kirsten mentions above, 'perspective'), such as acting on a user's behalf, requires a key. Kirsten's answer above is 100% correct.

Comment: Is there any easy way to obtain your own access token? I know you can get the one from Twitter from their developer website. Havent seen a similar option on the developer site of LinkedIn

Comment: In PHP, you could use the [Simple-LinkedIn](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/) library, install the demo scripts on your server and retrieve them that way.